# Semicolon separated list to cmake command in cmake file

Tags: amazon-web-services, cmake, aws-sdk

I am building amazon's aws-sdk-cpp in my application. So i am extracting the content from `aws-sdk-cpp.tar.gz` file and running as ExternalProject.

```
ExternalProject_Add(awssdk
    PREFIX DIR
    URL ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${AWS_SDK_SRC_TAR}
    BUILD_COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DBUILD_ONLY='dynamodb;kenisis' -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Ext/Aws/CtcInstall/${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX} -DENABLE_TESTING=OFF ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/source
```

But, when i pass `-DBUILD_ONLY='dynamodb;kenisis'`(supported by aws cmake file), Build is failing. If i pass `-DBUILD_ONLY=dynamodb` only dynamodb related targets are getting generated. But i need `kenisis` related targets also. How can i pass that semicolon separated list in ExternalProject_Add.

Comment: Are you just typoing that because it should be `kinesis`, surely?

Comment: Please give it a try with double-quotes. For more details on the single-/double-quotes issues in CMake's command line see e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37156362/how-to-preserve-single-quotes-in-a-cmake-cached-variable).

Comment: Have you tried `\;`?

Comment: Yes Florian, i have tried giving double quotes. But the error is `add_subdirectory given source "aws-cpp-sdk-"dynamodb" which is not an existing directory.` So instead of searching for `aws-cpp-sdk-dynamodb`, its searching for  `aws-cpp-sdk-"dynamodb`.

Comment: I have tried with `\"`(ERROR : As mentioned in above comment) and `\'`(ERROR : Invalid escape sequence \').

Comment: Have you tried storing the parameter in a cache file and passing it via `-C`?

Answer (score 7):

Doing some testing myself - including the hint in @usr1234567's comment - I did run the following successfully (for easier reproduciblility I've put the Git address in the example):

```
ExternalProject_Add(
    awssdk
    PREFIX DIR
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp.git
    CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS
        -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:String=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
        -DBUILD_ONLY:String=dynamodb\\;kinesis
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:String=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Ext/Aws/CtcInstall
        -DENABLE_TESTING:String=OFF
)
```

The awkward double backslashes are necessary because the `ExternalProject_Add()` itself is a CMake script function that goes through several loops of parameter extension.

**Alternative**

A more generic way would be to use a `$<SEMICOLON>` generator expression like this:

```
ExternalProject_Add(
    awssdk
    PREFIX DIR
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp.git
    CMAKE_ARGS
        -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
        -DBUILD_ONLY=dynamodb$<SEMICOLON>kinesis
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Ext/Aws/CtcInstall
        -DENABLE_TESTING=OFF
)
```

Just for demonstration purposes I'm also using an alternative way of passing the arguments here.

Comment: Also, when you are not putting the argument in place but expand it from a variable, you might need to escape the `;` as well to make sure the variable expansion does not introduce a break in the argument list. So in that case you need a string with a triple-backslash: `dynamodb\\\;kinesis`